# Filtering string column with specific character

Tags: python, mysql, sql, r

I have a string column like this and want to filter content between "/" character:

| A |
| --- |
| 9/17/**001.a.x.y.16.04451** |
| **006.b.021017006814** |
| 2/17/**000.c.m.n.15.00668**/008 |

And the expected output is

| A |
| --- |
| **001.a.x.y.16.04451** |
| **006.b.021017006814** |
| **000.c.m.n.15.00668** |

How could i make it done with ***python/R/Mysql***

Thank youuu

Comment: What is `a.x.y`, `c.m.n` etc?

Comment: They are random character A-Z or 0-9. Oh my bad when forgot to edit the input

Comment: @RonakShah I've just edited my question. Ty!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, you can use `regexp_replace()`:

```
select t.*,
       regexp_replace(a, '^[^/]+/[^/]+/([^/]*)[/|^]', '$1')
from t;
```

The logic is that you seem to want the third component between slashes if there is one.  Otherwise, you seem to want the entire string.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0c5c5eb55d1d68c95aeabc0516372ac7) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: @SonPham . . . Is there a reason you unaccepted this answer?